# How to make working function: DateAdd(getDate(), D, -2) //expiration date is less than 2 days from today

Tags: sql

**I have this homework to resolve :** "Select the rows where Balance is greater than 1000 and expiration date is less than 2 days from today."

**I've tried:**

```
SELECT FROM Account
WHERE Balance > 1000
AND ExpirationDate < DateAdd(getDate(), D, -2);

create table Account (
ID int,
Owner char(40),
Balance float,
CreationDate datetime,
ExpirationDate datetime 
)


insert into Account (ID, Owner, Balance, CreationDate, ExpirationDate) values 
(1 , 'Frank Lampard', 2000, '2006-06-01', '2022-03-01'),
(2 , 'Mike Lincoln', 1500, '2007-05-15', '2022-10-01'),
(3 , 'Matt Fraser', 4000, '2011-12-11', '2021-003-01'),
(4 , 'John Mc Donald', 3000, '2012-05-02', '2023-01-01'),
(5 , 'Elena Svitolina', 2800, '2007-02-06', '2022-04-01'),
(6 , 'Naomy Osaka', 5000, '2008-02-21', '2022-03-01'),
(7 , 'Jean Valjean', 1500, '20011-07-11', '2021-04-01'),
(8 , 'Adrian Svenson', 4500, '2009-08-20', '2024-05-01'),
(9 , 'Johnny Cash', 4000, '2010-05-11', '2021-01-01'),
(10 , 'Dan Simons', 2000, '2011-07-22', '2022-10-01');
```

I expect the output to be showing:

select the rows where Balance is greater than 1000 and expiration date is less than 2 days from today

The output is:

> Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "FROM": syntax error)

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should not use the `char` data type. Use `varchar` instead.

Comment: Three things wrong with the data model:  `name` should be `varchar()` not `char()`. 
 dates should be `date`, not `datetime`.  Monetary amounts should be stored as `numeric` not `float`.  I'm not impressed by your class assignment.

Answer (score 0):

First, to address the error you're getting, note that you are missing a select list.

Second, you have the arguments of [`DateAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the wrong order:

```
SELECT *
-- Here^
FROM   Account
WHERE  Balance > 1000 AND ExpirationDate < DateAdd(d, -2, GetDate())
```

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you all guys, for trying to help me. I do it in your way and now I have this error: Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such column: D)

Comment: If this is really the only problem, then you should just vote to close as a typo.

Comment: @M.Bulumac I missed the misuse of `dateadd` - see my edited answer.

Comment: Nope, same error:  Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such column: d)

Answer (score 0):

Because `getdate()` has a time component and the sample data does not, I interpret the "less than 2 days from today" as a comparison without the time component.  I think the appropriate logic is:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Account a
WHERE a.Balance > 1000 AND
      a.ExpirationDate < DateAdd(day, -2, CONVERT(date, getDate()));
```

Notes:

- This introduces table aliases (the `a`)
- This qualifies all column names, which is a best practice (and adds the missing expressions in the `SELECT`).
- This spells out the date part (i.e. using `day` instead of `d`), which is also a best practice.

EDIT:

The above syntax is just fine for SQL Server, which appears to be what you want.  However, if you are not using SQL Server, it is not going to work (probably).  The standard syntax would be:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Account a
WHERE a.Balance > 1000 AND
      a.ExpirationDate < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '2 day';
```

Comment: It doesn't work . Same error: Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such column: day)